# advantages of serving via asset pipeline rather than from /public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have an app that serves web image assets from both locations. I have watched the two railscasts on this topic but what are the REAL advantages of serving images this way. I see the timestamp on the file; does this cause problems with working with a CDN like cloudfront? Or a reverse proxy such as Varnish? Are there any performance metrics for serving from /public vs /app/assets using Nginx?

In short, I understand advantages of CSS and Javascript but am not sure if it justifies moving the images from /public to /app/assets. What is the most compelling reason to do so? And are there any significant downsides esp as it relates to a CDN?

thx

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline will ad a digest (digital signature) to the images which is very helpful for cache busting. If you do eventually choose to use a CDN, having all your static assets in the assets folder makes it convenient.

Comment: one issue I noticed is that if referenced, in javascript, you'll get two copies. one with digest and one without. kinda introduces new problems but helpful

Comment: That shouldnt happen, are you using the asset_path helper method?

Comment: let me look into it. Maybe different file in /lib or /vendor. Seems like a major flaw that this isn't namespaced better